# Spring creating bean but not injecting it

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired, inject

I know theres a ton of questions regarding problems with Spring Autowired, but I havent been able to find anything similar to mine, so sorry if its a dupe...

Im having problems with autowiring a bean that is created (debugging shows that the constructor is run), but then it doesnt get injected. There are no calls of manual instantiation.
I have many other autowired fields in the project and they work fine.
Most amusing, though, is the fact that Ive used the same pattern and config in a different project *and it works there*...

Now then, here are the codes:

The bean that gets created but not injected:

```
@Component("genericDao")
public class GenericHibernateJpaDao implements GenericDao {

    @Autowired
    protected EntityManagerFactory entityManagerfactory;

    public GenericHibernateJpaDao() {
    }
    //getters, setters and dao methods
}
```

GenericDao interface only defines methods and has no annotations.

Service super-class that defines the bean:

```
@Configurable
public abstract class AbstractService {
    @Autowired
    protected GenericDao genericDao;
    //getters, setters
}
```

Service implementation (declaration bit):

```
@Service
@Component
public class WechatMessageService extends AbstractService implements IMessageService {
```

Breakpoint in service implementation at `genericDao.saveOrUpdate(n);` shows genericDao to be null (this is also the line that throws NullPointerEx.)
IMessageService is

```
@Service
@Configurable
@Transactional
```

application-config.xml (relevant bits):

```
<beans .......... default-autowire="byName">
    <context:component-scan base-package="package.with.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="package.with.service" />
    <context:spring-configured/>
```

Im guessing its just some fairly stupid mistake on my side, but I just cant figure it out and googling isnt helping.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: (1) Unless your logic is really out of ordinary, use Spring Data instead of writing your own DAO. (2) Use `@PersistenceUnit` to inject a JPA EMF.

Comment: @chrylis first time hearing about Spring Data, will have to take a look...
also im using `<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">` in app-config for the EMF

Comment: @Configurable needs load time weaving. Have you enabled that?

Comment: You'd get a wiring exception if Spring attempted to wire and failed. Despite what you said, I suspect a non-managed bean.

Comment: @chrylis when I replaced the non-parameter constructor for a parametered one it threw bean creation exception saying it couldnt find a suitable constructor

Comment: Did you have a constructor marked `@Autowired`?

Comment: I just realized something... I am using the service in test context, where I initialize the service manually because I need to pass it a dummy for an underlying library.
Oh my god. It didnt occur to me until now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I was mistaken in my premise during debugging.
While I had no manual initiation of the DAO bean, I was creating a manual instance of the *service* in the initialization of the tests, because I needed to pass it a dummy object.
So yeah...

Thanks to everyone for the help though, as it nudged me to this realization and helped me understand Spring and its annotations better.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have load-time weaving enabled (in order to work with AspectJ), you wouldn't need to use the `@Configurable` annotation.

Try removing `@Configurable` from `AbstractService`, as it's an abstract class. Also remove `@Component` from `WechatMessageService`, because you already have `@Service`, so there's no need for `@Component`.

Try the following for your `AbstractService` class:

```
public abstract class AbstractService {
    @Resource(name = "genericDao")
    protected GenericDao genericDao;
    //getters, setters
}
```

Autowiring by name is better performed with `@Resource`, so you don't need to use qualifiers.