# Spring beans created but not autowired

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I know there are so many similar questions about this. I looked through a lot of them but the problem still remains.

I have a service that gets created but is not autowired. There is no(!) manual initiation, neither in the project nor in tests (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259464/spring-creating-bean-but-not-injecting-it))

Both beans are found and created, says Tomcat output. At least the first service is not injected where it should be. I don't know about the second one.

Service (Interface):

```
public interface SchoolService {
  public School getSchool(String id);
}
```

Service (Implementation):

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SchoolServiceImpl implements SchoolService {

  @Autowired
  private SchoolDAO schoolDAO;

  public School getSchool(String id) {
    //database things
    return school;
  }

}
```

Where it gets "called"

```
public class SchoolMenu implements Serializable {

  @Autowired
  private SchoolService schoolService;

  public SchoolMenu () {
    //here schoolService is null
    School school = schoolService.getSchool("id");
  }

}
```

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


    <bean id="SchoolServiceImpl" class="content_management.School.service.SchoolServiceImpl"/>
    <bean id="SchoolDAOImpl" class="content_management.School.dao.SchoolDAOImpl"/>
</beans>
```

Tomcat Output:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@57003970: defining beans [SchoolServiceImpl,SchoolDAOImpl]; root of factory hierarchy
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'SchoolServiceImpl'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating instance of bean 'SchoolServiceImpl'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Eagerly caching bean 'SchoolServiceImpl' to allow for resolving potential circular references
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Finished creating instance of bean 'SchoolServiceImpl'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'SchoolDAOImpl'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating instance of bean 'SchoolDAOImpl'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Eagerly caching bean 'SchoolDAOImpl' to allow for resolving potential circular references
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Finished creating instance of bean 'SchoolDAOImpl'
```

Where is my error?

Comment: You're attempting to use the field from the constructor, before Spring has had a chance to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

In order for `@Autowired` to work, `SchoolMenu` also has to be a Spring bean. If it is not, you can get `schoolService` from application context. Something like this

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
SchoolService schoolService = (SchoolService) appContext.getBean(SchoolService.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing `schoolService` in the constructor of `SchoolMenu`:

```
public SchoolMenu () {
    //here schoolService is null
    School school = schoolService.getSchool("id");
}
```

At that point, `schoolService` is not yet injected. It couldn't be - nothing can happen *before* the constructor has been invoked.

You can declare a method to be invoked after the bean is initialized, by annotating it with the `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` annotation. Perform actions that need the injected dependencies in that method, not in the constructor.

(There are a few other ways to achieve the same, such as implementing the `InitializingBean` interface, but these are a bit outdated)

Example:

```
public SchoolMenu () {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // schoolService is NOT null here
    School school = schoolService.getSchool("id");
}
```

Comment: Even more preferable is to use constructor injection in the first place.

Comment: Constructor injection has many advantages, but one big disadvantage: it can't resolve cycles in dependencies (two services referring to each other using constructor injection cannot be initialized - at least one of them needs setter or field injection)

Comment: Yes, but (1) that's not the case here as far as I can tell and (2) cyclic dependencies are nearly always a sign of a design problem.

Comment: Citation for (2)? I have never encountered a situation in which constructor injection provides a dependency that isn't "constructed" per CDI.

Comment: You're right about initialization, constructor arguments are fully initialized. I guess that's why you get cyclic dependency errors more often than you would expect if this wasn't a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining beans in xml, you can use component scan by adding this config to your application-context and Spring will scan and detect the bean automatically for you.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="content_management.School" />
```

Also you need to add in the context namespace so the application-context.xml will look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="content_management.School" />

 </beans>
```

Comment: I added both namespace and scan snippet, but I get `XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 26 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 78; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: `

Comment: Can you show line 26 of your applicationContext.xml or even better the whole file? Seems like syntax error

Comment: line 26 is the `<context: ...` line, I just cropped some comments in between

Comment: Sorry I miss out the schemaLocation for context. I have updated my answer. Also verify that the base-package  is correct. It must point to the package which contains both your SchoolDAO and SchoolService.